# How to set range as variable based on changing height of data

Tags: google-apps-script

The code below takes the same range of data from multiple files in a folder.  However, it only uses data in that range if it meets a criteria.  So, the returned values from each file vary in height.

I have put a ??? indicating where I need the height of the range I am writing that data to to change for each loop based on the height of the data I am collecting from each file.

```
function getAllData() {
var folder = DocsList.getFolderById("folderid");
var contents = folder.getFiles();
Logger.log("file length: " + contents.length);

var file;
var data;

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Base")
sheet.clearContents();



var numOfFiles = contents.length;

for (var i = 0; i < numOfFiles; i++) {
file = contents[i];
Logger.log("count: "  + i);

var theFileType = file.getFileType();
Logger.log("theFileType: " + theFileType);

if (theFileType==DocsList.FileType.SPREADSHEET) {

var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.open(file).getSheetByName("Sheet 1");
var lastLine = sheet2.getLastRow();
var values = sheet2.getRange('A3:J').getValues();
var formulas = sheet2.getRange('A3:J').getFormulas();

var data = [];

  for(var row = 0 ; row < (values).length ; row++){

var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow()+1;
if (values[row][0] != '')  {

for(var col = 0 ; col < formulas[row].length ; col++){
    if(formulas[row][col] != '')
      {values[row][col] = formulas[row][col]};


  data.push(values[row]);}
  if(data.length > 0)
  sheet.getRange(lastrow, 1, ???, data[0].length).setValues(data);

  } 
}

  };
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's only 1 valid value in the "???", and it is "data.length", do you really want to setValues() everytime in the loop? Shouldn't it be better to build all the data then output all at once?

Comment: I dont know... what would that look like?

Comment: Placing the `sheet.getRange(lastrow, 1, ???, data[0].length).setValues(data);` after the `for` and changing ??? with data.length.

Comment: No go, it is still using the length the data (meaning columns) and not the height (rows) so it is reporting that the expected height of the data is wrong.